# i.MX6 SABRE Yocto Pocky with Midori error: No package 'webkit-1.0' found

Tags: compiler-errors, webkit, yocto, openembedded, midori

I'm trying to compile the Yocto Pocky linux with Midori 0.5.2 browser (web kiosk image) and I get the next error (after solving a lot of previously errors):

> ...
>
> | Checking for x11                            : 1.6.3
>
> | Checking for header X11/extensions/scrnsaver.h : yes
>
> | Checking for library Xss                       : yes
>
> | Checking for gtk+-2.0 >= 2.16.0                : 2.24.28
>
> | Checking for webkit-1.0 >= 1.1.17              : Package webkit-1.0
>   was not found in the pkg-config search path.
>
> | **Perhaps you should add the directory containing `webkit-1.0.pc'**
>
> | **to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable**
>
> | **No package 'webkit-1.0' found**
>
> |
>   /home/jdavid/workspace/Yocto_k4/fsl-release-bsp/kiosk-build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/midori/0.5.2-r0/midori-0.5.2/wscript:190: error: the configuration failed (see
>   '/home/jdavid/workspace/Yocto_k4/fsl-release-bsp/kiosk-build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/midori/0.5.2-r0/midori-0.5.2/_build/config.log')
>
> | WARNING: exit code 2 from a shell command.
>
> | ERROR: Function failed: do_configure (log file is located at
>   /home/jdavid/workspace/Yocto_k4/fsl-release-bsp/kiosk-build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/midori/0.5.2-r0/temp/log.do_configure.20685)
>
> ERROR: Task 1768
>   (/home/jdavid/workspace/Yocto_k4/fsl-release-bsp/sources/meta-web-kiosk/recipes-browser/midori/midori_0.5.2.bb,
>   do_configure) failed with exit code '1' ...

The PKG_CONFIG_PATH variable is set properly, including the directory which contains the "webkit-1.0.pc" file.

I'm installed all required libraries and dependencies that I've found as solutions but not work for me:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libunique-dev libnotify libgtk2.0-dev libwebkit-dev libxml2-dev libsoup2.4-dev libsqlite3-dev valac libwebkitgtk-1.0-0  libwebkitgtk-1.0-common libwebkitgtk-common-dev libwebkit-dev libwebkit1.1-cil libwebkit-cil-dev libzeitgeist-1.0-1 libzeitgeist-dev
$ pkg-config —modversion webkit-1.0
```

and I also execute this commands that I see in one post:

```
$ cd $HOME/workspace/Yocto_k4/fsl-release-bsp/kiosk-build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/midori/0.5.2-r0/midori-0.5.2/
$ ./waf configure $ ./waf build $ sudo ./waf install
```

and work fine but compiling image continue failing.

The bitbake command is the next:

```
$ bitbake core-image-web-kiosk
```

Extra info:

- OS: Ubuntu 14.04.
- Device: imx6dlsabre for smart devices

bblayers.conf:

```
LCONF_VERSION = "6"

BBPATH = "${TOPDIR}" BSPDIR := "${@os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(d.getVar('FILE', True)) + '/../..')}"

BBFILES ?= "" 
BBLAYERS = " \   
${BSPDIR}/sources/poky/meta \   
${BSPDIR}/sources/poky/meta-yocto \   
\   
${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-oe \   
${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-multimedia \   
\   
${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-fsl-arm \   
${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-fsl-arm-extra \   
${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-fsl-demos \ "

##Freescale Yocto Project Release layer 

BBLAYERS += " ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-fsl-bsp-release/imx/meta-bsp " 
BBLAYERS += " ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-fsl-bsp-release/imx/meta-sdk " 
BBLAYERS += " ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-browser " 
BBLAYERS += " ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-gnome " 
BBLAYERS += " ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-networking " 
BBLAYERS += " ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-python " 
BBLAYERS += " ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-ruby " 
BBLAYERS += " ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-filesystems " 
BBLAYERS += " ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-xfce " 
BBLAYERS += " ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-qt5 " 
BBLAYERS += " ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-webkit " 
BBLAYERS += " ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-web-kiosk "
```

local.conf:

```
MACHINE ??= 'imx6dlsabresd'
DISTRO ?= 'fsl-imx-x11'
PACKAGE_CLASSES ?= "package_rpm"
EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES = "debug-tweaks"
USER_CLASSES ?= "buildstats image-mklibs"
PATCHRESOLVE = "noop"
BB_DISKMON_DIRS = "\
    STOPTASKS,${TMPDIR},1G,100K \
    STOPTASKS,${DL_DIR},1G,100K \
    STOPTASKS,${SSTATE_DIR},1G,100K \
    STOPTASKS,/tmp,100M,100K \
    ABORT,${TMPDIR},100M,1K \
    ABORT,${DL_DIR},100M,1K \
    ABORT,${SSTATE_DIR},100M,1K \
    ABORT,/tmp,10M,1K"
PACKAGECONFIG_append_pn-qemu-native = " sdl"
PACKAGECONFIG_append_pn-nativesdk-qemu = " sdl"
ASSUME_PROVIDED += "libsdl-native"
CONF_VERSION = "1"

DISTRO_FEATURES_append = " opengl x11"
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " kernel-modules webkitgtk-bin"
PREFERRED_VERSION_webkitgtk = "2.8.5"

BB_NUMBER_THREADS = '2'
PARALLEL_MAKE = '-j 2'

DL_DIR ?= "${BSPDIR}/downloads/"
ACCEPT_FSL_EULA = "1"
```

Can anyone help me to solve this error? Thanks.

Comment: Nope, cannot reproduce your error.  I am using Midori 0.4.5 and OE core webkitgtk-1.8.3. and your bblayer and local.conf are missing.

Comment: Sorry @CharlesC. , I add the local and blayers files. I try before with Midori 0.4.5 but I got the same error. How yo specify to use the webkitgtk-1.8.3 version?

Comment: What branch of the Yocto is using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue using a Ubuntu 12.04 instead of 14.04.

It seems only a repo webkit version problem (2.24.X vs 1.8.X).

Answer (score 0):

remove `meta-webkit` from `bblayers.conf` and

clean the build by using `bitbake -c cleansstate webkitgtk`

openembedded-core has `webkitgtk` itself and we could use that one instead of the most updated one from `meta-webkit`.

One more thing is that `meta-web-kiosk` is not updated for 2 years.  You shall switch to use Qt WebEngine instead.

Comment: I have made these changes but still fails. Finally, I solved the issue using a Ubuntu 12.04 instead of 14.04, It seems a webkit version problem.

Answer (score 0):

On Debian Unstable 4.13.0-1-amd64 I found that dependencies under:

```
sudo apt install libwebkitgtk-dev
```